# VB.NET Repeating getting Properties from a Document when passed to a Sub, that could be more convenient, but how?

Tags: vb.net, properties

In a program I often pass on oDoc to different Subs, oDoc is always unique.
In the receiving Subs I always want to have access to the Properties that oDoc contains.
So I request that again in every sub, see code, and that about eleven times.
I do this via a Sub that works fine for that, by the way.
I think that could be much more convenient.
But I don't know exactly how.
How do I best improve that?

```
' Get Properties
        Dim sPartNumber As String = GetProp(oDoc, "DTP", "Part Number")
        Dim sRev As String = GetProp(oDoc, "ISI", "Revision Number")
        Dim sDescription As String = GetProp(oDoc, "DTP", "Description")
        Dim sMaterial As String = GetProp(oDoc, "DTP", "Material")
        Dim sThickness As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Thickness")   
        Dim sFinishing As String  = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Finishing")
        Dim sFabrication As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Fabrication")
        Dim sBends As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Bends")
        Dim sTAPPING As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "TAPPING")
        Dim sCSINK As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "CSINK")
        Dim sCBORE As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "CBORE")
        Dim sUnderClassApproval As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Under Class Approval")
        Dim sPartParameters As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "PartParameters")
        Dim sMass As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Mass")
        Dim sCombinedProductionOutput As String = GetProp(oDoc, "IUDP", "Combined Production Output")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single method that extracts those values and loads them into a simpler object, e.g. an array or a `Dictionary` or an object of a dedicated type. You could then put that object in a commonly-accessible location or pass it explicitly to each method that needs the data. You're still going to have to get the data out of that object when it's needed but I suspect that that will be more efficient than getting it out of the Word document object each time.

Comment: Thanks for your response and tips.
For completeness, oDoc refers to an AutoDesk Inventor Document with all its properties inside that document, not a Word document :-)
In practice, I can imagine having one Sub that receives oDoc where those GetProp actions take place.
But then I don't know how I can pass all those properties to a receiving Sub, at least not simply and efficiently.
Previously I made the same list of properties for every receiving Sub, but that is difficult to manage and I don't think it is really professional.
Maybe you can/can someone push me in the right direction?